# How to pass a input parameter of a UnityEvent to its listener in the inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I have a UnityEvent<int> declared like this:

```
public UnityEvent<int> onValueChanged;
```

and inside the Unity inspector, i want to pass the integer parameter of the event to its listener like in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOg4X.png). Is there a way to do this? I know it is possible to do in code using delegates but is there a way to do it only in the inspector?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity cannot serialize generics properly (except for `List<T>` and arrays). That's why you can't see it in the inspector.

If you want to expose a generic parameter, you have to create a type for it. It doesn't even require any code, the type itself is enough.

```
[Serializable]
public class IntUnityEvent : UnityEvent<int>
{
}

public class YourClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public IntUnityEvent ExposedEvent;
}
```

---

I should add that you have could just open the documentation, as Unity tells you exactly the same on their documentation page for [`UnityEvent<T0>`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent_1.html).